# Gravity Forms Post method

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a simple form that users will fill out which will in turn become a post on my site. I have 2 problems:

1. I am using the Post title, Post Custom Field elements (for single line text) and Post Body element (for paragraph text). When I submit my test form though, only the title is appearing, none of the data I wrote in the custom field elements.
2. Is there a setting I can  use to have the title of fields show up in my post? (i.e, Name field would actually show "Name: Whatever the user typed in" on the post?) When I was able to get one of the body fields to appear on the post, it only had the information I typed in, not the title.

Maybe I am not using the post fields correctly, so any direction/opinions would help!

Thanks

Comment: Hold tight, Craigy - I have an answer that may be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a video for you showing you how to use the content template in Gravity Forms, which is the key to formatting content within the post body.

Take a look here: http://www.screenr.com/sYT8

If you find yourself needing to do more advanced work, then you'll probably want to investigate setting up a custom template and pulling in the data from the custom fields directly into the template.

As for question #1, it sounds like the field might not be properly configured. Can you post a screenshot or video of the settings?

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the video -- my problem was solved! Really, thank you so much for the time it took to make that video.

Comment: You are welcome! Very happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, I would use custom field names. WordPress uses "name" and various other things, probably title, so the form will not work properly. So just put some special characters before the form names and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I completely get what you're saying. Do I need to use special characters in the form fields or in the titles of the form fields?